# ms word's images disappears after 10 sec after when I open it

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a ms word document which I'm creating it apache poi with java. This document has a lot of images because of that the word document's size is too big (like 300 mb). When I open the document, it's freezing and the images disappears like this.

[image]

I'm putting images in ms word like this

```
int picturesCount=imgPaths.size();  
            int tableRows=(int)Math.round(picturesCount/2d);
            XWPFParagraph parag=document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run=parag.createRun();
            InputStream is2 = null;

            XWPFTable imgTable;
            XWPFTableCell cell;
            int TableRows=0;
            for(int f=0;f<imgPaths.size();f++)
            {
                if(!imgPaths.get(f).equals("-"))
                {
                    TableRows++;
                }
            }
            int rows=(int)Math.round(TableRows/2d);
            imgTable=document.createTable(rows,2);
            imgTable.removeBorders();
            int tableRow=0;
            int tableCell=0;
            int des=0;
            for(String pictureURL:imgPaths) {

                if(!"-".equals(pictureURL)) {
                    try {

                        cell=imgTable.getRow(tableRow).getCell(tableCell++);
                        if(tableCell==2) {
                            tableCell=0;
                            tableRow++;
                        }

                        is2 = new FileInputStream(pictureURL);
                        if(cell.getParagraphs().size()>0) parag=cell.getParagraphs().get(0);else parag=cell.addParagraph();
                        if(parag.getRuns().size()>0) run=parag.getRuns().get(0);else run=parag.createRun();
                        run.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "Images", Units.toEMU(250), Units.toEMU(250));
                        parag=cell.addParagraph();
                        run.setText(des_img.get(des));
                        des++;
                        run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).getInlineArray(0).addNewCNvGraphicFramePr().addNewGraphicFrameLocks().setNoChangeAspect(true);

                    }  catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

How do I solve this problem any suggestion??

Comment: Not using that many pictures maybe? Nobody wants to handle a 300MB word file. Its way too slow, because word just can't handle that

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have to use many pictures because I'm getting a report from access database that has many pictures.

Comment: Then split it up. word files you want to handle should at max be 20MB. And btw, vanishing content is an issue of word and none caused by apache poi

Comment: Try writing it into a form of PDF, if you can. MS Word cannot handle the size of 300 MB.

Comment: How big are the single `JPEG` files in bytes? Maybe you could scaling them to lower size using `BufferedImage` before embedding them into word? Of course scaling to lower size always means less quality too.

Comment: @AxelRichter My bigger image file almost 6 mb but there are so many images like this. I used to try **BufferedImage** but it's not useful for me :(